# Какой Golang шаблонизатор выбрать и как подключить файлы динамически?

Tags: golang, шаблоны

Использую стандартный шаблонизатор Go.
Есть 2 вопроса
1. Нужно запустить функцию, прописанную в самом шаблоне
2. Нужно подключить файл, прописанный в шаблоне

Ну что-то типа такого

```
<html>
{{ GetFile "/tpl/myfile.tpl" }}
{{ SayHello }}  //а функция возратит текст
</html>
```

Как такое реализовать?
Я читал доки, но подкл файлы динамически не могу- только в коде go есть примеры, да и с функциями танец с бубнами что-то.

Comment: Посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200178/call-a-method-from-a-go-template и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206467/go-how-to-render-multiple-templates-in-golang возможно решит ваши проблемы

Comment: Запустить файл - это значит вставить другой шаблон на это место? Функция своя?

Answer (score 1):

Для включения кода другого шаблона используйте

```
{{template "base/footer.html"}}
```

Для использования своих функций пишутся FuncMap(пакет "html/template"):

```
    func loadTemplate(Name string) *html.Template {
    funcMap := html.FuncMap{
        "foo": func(val string) html.HTML {
            return html.HTML(val)
        },
    }

    return html.Must(html.New("*").Funcs(funcMap).Delims("{{", "}}").ParseFiles("template/" + Name + ".tpl")) 
}
```

Затем в шаблоне используем так:

```
<h1>{{ .var | foo }}</h1>
```